# Why does .* fail to match the entire (rest of the) string in this regex?

Tags: c#, regex

I ran into a problem with my regular expressions, I'm using regular expressions for obtaining data from the string below:

```
 "# DO NOT EDIT THIS MAIL BY HAND #\r\n\r\n[Feedback]:hallo\r\n\r\n# DO NOT EDIT THIS MAIL BY HAND #\r\n\r\n"
```

So far I got it working with:

```
String sFeedback = Regex.Match(Message, @"\[Feedback\]\:(?<string>.*?)\r\n\r\t\n# DO NOT EDIT THIS MAIL BY HAND #").Groups[1].Value;
```

This works except if the header is changed, therefore I want the regex to read from `[feedback]:` to the end of the string. (symbols, ascii, everything..)

I tried: `\[Feedback]:(?<string>.*?)$`

Above regular expression does work in some regular expression builders online but in my c# code its not working and returns a empty string. What's wrong?

Comment: what is the result you want from the given string?

Comment: I would like to get all chars from the [Feedback]: ...... till end of the string, this could be numbers/text/symbols/other languages ect

Comment: @Benjol It means it will match the smallest sequence that works instead of the longest. So for example in the string `aabaab`, `.*b` will match `aabaab` but `.*?b` will match `aab`. In this case it is pointless since it is immediately followed by the end of string/line marker so the shortest and longest matches are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `.` doesn't match newlines unless you use `RegexOptions.Singleline` when compiling the regex or inline it using  `(?s)`:

```
(?s)\[Feedback\]:(.*)$
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the escape character.

Also, since you are not referring to the group by name in your C# code, you could further simplify your regex to this

```
\[Feedback\]:(.*)$
```

Comment: The escape character is not needed in this case. It's clear from context that it's a verbatim `]`, and the .NET regex engine knows how to handle this.

Comment: Cool, that's really interesting. Did not know that about C#!

Comment: Most regex engines do this correctly, but since some have quirks, I usually use the escapes to keep things simple. For example, in .NET, `[][]` is a valid character class, but in Java, you need to write `"[]\\[]"`.

Answer (score 0):

`$` in regex means:

> The match must occur at the end of the string or before `\n` at the end of the line or string.

and `.` means:

> Matches any single character except `\n`.

try to use this simple regex:

```
\[Feedback\]:(?<string>.*)
```

Comment: With `Multiline` you would not get the entire string after `[Feedback]:`, just the part until the following linebreak.

Comment: That was one of the problems I've runned into :P